# Laravel and react, How to give a notification from Laravel to my react application (Unexpected use of 'self' no restricted-globals error)

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, function, api

I can create Notifications In laravel and in React. I have followed the tutorials, but I don't know how to send the notification from laravel to my react application. This is the code that I got in my  Laravel Controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Feature\HttpHandler;
use App\Notifications\PushDemo;
use App\Models\Users;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use NotificationChannels\WebPush\PushSubscription;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use App\Feature\ApiResponse;


class PushController extends Controller
{
    use ApiResponse;
    use HttpHandler;

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function push(){
        Log::info('Push push function  called');
        $users = Users::all();
        Notification::send($users,new PushDemo);
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info('Push store called');
        // get user from request
        //$user = Users::findOrFail($request->userId);
        
        $user = Users::whereUrl($request->post('URL'))->firstOrFail();
        $b = $request['body'];

        // create PushSubscription and connect to this user
        $pushsub = $user->updatePushSubscription($request->body['endpoint'], $request->body['keys']['p256dh'], $request->body['keys']['auth']);

        Log::info('WORKED');
        return $pushsub;
    }
    
}
```

The store function works.
In react I have this piece of code in my service-worker.js to listen to a event. (this is the piece of code that needs to work, but it says unexpected use of 'self' no restriced-globals)

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (e) {
  console.log('push');
  if (!(self.Notification && self.Notification.permission === 'granted')) {
      //notifications aren't supported or permission not granted!
      return;
  }

  if (e.data) {
      var msg = e.data.json();
      console.log(msg)
      e.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(msg.title, {
          body: msg.body,
          icon: msg.icon,
          actions: msg.actions
      }));
  }
});
```

This code is never called it seems but it should be called when I click on this button:

```
<button onClick={() => test()}>
  test notification
</button>
```

This is the function to go through the Laravel application:

```
function test(){
    console.log('test');
    workerApi.makePushNotification({ URL, token})
          .then(response => {

              if (response.hasOwnProperty('message') && response.hasOwnProperty('type')) {

              }
              else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                  
              }
          })
          })
  }
```

This function call works. only it seemd like the service worker function is never called and it doesn't send the notification to my react application. How do I solve this?

Comment: For live notifications i recommend laravel-websocket it's free and open source
you can make a new event for notification and dispatch and laravel echo will catch on front end

Answer (score 0):

hey you should use some real-time library for listener real-time events like pusher then you can send the message from the server to the frontend

for installing pusher on laravel application please check this article
https://www.codecheef.org/article/real-time-event-broadcasting-with-laravel-6-and-pusher

and for your react app

npm install --save pusher-js

your component file

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

 useEffect(() => {
     var pusher = new Pusher("your-pusher-key", {
       cluster: "ap2",
       encrypted: true,
     });

     var channel = pusher.subscribe("notifyChannel");
      channel.bind("notifyChannel", async function (response) {
          alert('some notification');
      })
});
```